# Categories of modules and inverse homomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, modules

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$I have two equivalent rings $R$ and $S$ with $F$ and $G$ inverse equivalent functors, $F : {}_{R}\mathsf{M} \to {}_{S}\mathsf{M}$ and $G$ inverse. So I have 2 natural isomorphisms $\eta:GF \to 1_{{}_{R}\mathsf{M}}$ and $\zeta:FG \to 1_{{}_{S}\mathsf{M}}$.

This means that for every left $R$-module $M$ and for every left $S$-module $N$ there are isomorphisms
\begin{gather*}
  \eta_M:GF(M) \to M \\
  \zeta_N: FG(N) \to N
\end{gather*}
such that for every morphism $f:M \to M'$ and $g:N \to N'$ the diagrams are commutative, so:
\begin{align*}
  \eta_{M'} \circ GF(f) &= f \circ \eta_M \\
  \zeta_{N'} \circ FG(g) &= g \circ \zeta_N
\end{align*}

For every left $R$-module $M$ and every left $S$-module $N$ I have two isomorphisms of abelian groups:
\begin{align*}
  \phi:\Hom_S(N,F(M)) &\to \Hom_R(G(N), M) \\
  \theta:\Hom_S(F(M),N) &\to \Hom_R(M,G(N))
\end{align*}
such that
\begin{align*}
  \phi&: \gamma \to \eta_M\circ G(\gamma) \\
  \theta&: \delta \to G(\delta) \circ \eta_{M}^{-1}
\end{align*}

I need to write down what $\phi^{-1}$ and $\theta^{-1}$ are. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$Let $\gamma:N\to F(M)$ and $\phi(\gamma)=\eta_M\circ G(\gamma):G(N)\to M$.
Then $F(\eta_M^{-1}\circ\phi(\gamma))=FG(\gamma)=\zeta_{F(M)}^{-1}\circ\gamma\circ\zeta_N$ by the commutativity of the following diagram:

$$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
    FG(N)
    @> \zeta_N >>
    N
    \\
    @V FG(\gamma) VV
    {}
    @VV \gamma V
    \\
    FGF(M)
    @>> \zeta_{F(M)} > F(M)
  \end{CD}
$$

Consequently $\gamma=\zeta_{F(M)}\circ F(\eta_M^{-1}\circ\phi(\gamma))\circ\zeta_N^{-1}$
hence
$$\phi^{-1}(\xi)=\zeta_{F(M)}\circ F(\eta_M^{-1}\circ\xi)\circ\zeta_N^{-1}.$$

---

$\newcommand\Mod[1]{{}_{#1}\mathsf{M}}\newcommand\op{\mathsf{op}}\newcommand\Ab{\mathsf{Ab}}$We have two functors
\begin{align}
&\Hom_S(-,F(-)):\Mod S^\op\times\Mod R\to\Ab,&
&\Hom_R(G(-),-):\Mod S^\op\times\Mod R\to\Ab
\end{align}
controvariant in the first entry and covariant in the second entry.
For an $S$-module $N$ and an $R$-module $M$, the sets $\Hom_S(N,F(M))$ and $\Hom_R(G(N),M)$ are abelian groups respect to pointwise addition.
For example, if $\gamma_1,\gamma_2\in\Hom_S(N,F(M))$ then
\begin{align}
&\gamma_1+\gamma_2\in\Hom_S(N,F(M)),&
&(\gamma_1+\gamma_2)(x)=\gamma_1(x)+\gamma_2(x),&
&(x\in N).
\end{align}
Then we have a natural isomorphism $\phi:\Hom_S(-,F(-))\to\Hom_R(G(-),-)$.

Comment: Thank you! I'll think about it! By the way, my book says that $\phi$ and $\theta$ are natural isomorphisms. I know that a natural isomorphism is a natural transformation,  betweend functors. So, is it true that $\phi$ and $\theta$ are functors? How can I see it?

Comment: $\phi$ is a natural isomorphism from the functor $\Hom_S(-,F(-))$ to the functor $\Hom_R(G(-),-)$.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I have to use hom functors. Searching definition on my book, it defines: $Hom_R(U, -)$ for an $(R,S)$ bimodule $U$. In my situation I only know that $M$ is a left $R$-module and $N$ a left $S$-module. Is it a problem?

Comment: It's ok because you consider $\Hom_R(-,-)$ and $\Hom_S(-,-)$ as abelian groups.

Comment: So I'm working in the category of abelian groups now and I use the definition of hom functor for an arbitrary category, not for the modules one, right?

Comment: Please can you help me understand how these hom functors work? I've never met them before. Thanks!

Comment: I know that for example $\phi$ is the composition of the homomorphism of abelian groups induced by $G$, $Hom_S(N, F(M)) \to Hom_R(G(N), GF(M))$ and $Hom_R(G(N), \eta_M): Hom_R(G(N), GF(M)) \to Hom_R(G(N), M)$. How can I put together all these things to understand why is $\phi$ a functor?

Comment: You description of $\phi $ is correct, but    $\phi $ is a natural transformation rather than a functor.

Comment: The functors $\Hom_R $ and $\Hom_S $ are the usual ones for modules which are endowed with abelian group structure.

Comment: Yes, right, $\phi$ is not a functor. How do the functors $Hom_R$ and $Hom_S$ work?

Comment: I've searched in my books, I've found this definition: Let $U$ an $(R,S)$-bimodule. Then $Hom_R(U, -):{}_{R}\mathsf{M} \to {}_{S}\mathsf{M}$ is a covariant functor and $Hom_R(U, -):{}_{R}\mathsf{M} \to \mathsf{M}_S$ is a controvariant functor. Who is $U$ in my situation? I'm not sure about this bimodule, I don't have anyone

Comment: Do I have to regard to the modules only as abelian groups? I know that Hom_R(-,-) are abelian groups but with the definition of hom functor in my book I think that I must have bimodules inside brackets

Comment: I'm still searching so I add things. I can fix either $M$ or $N$ so I have two natural isomorphism in only one variable. Is $Hom_R(P, -): {}_{R}\mathsf{M} \to \mathsf{Ab}$ category of abelian group that sends $M$ to $Hom_R(P,M)$?

Comment: I added some detail in my aswer above.

Comment: Thanks, now it's all clearer! one last thing, why have you written the opposite ring?

Comment: Sorry, I've seen that you are talking about opposite category

Comment: I've searched something and I think that we have to use opposite category because we have to reverse the usual order of composition of morphisms, because in the category of left module we consider morphisms operating on the right (or is it only for enomorphisms?)

Comment: Opposite category because of contravariance in the first component.

Comment: ok I've understood. Thanks a lot for your help!